# script tag is not detected in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, detection

This is my jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>error</title>
</head>
<body>

No user found

</body>
</html>
```

This is the project file structure:

[image]

This is what I can see when I click view page source from browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>error</title>
</head>
<body>
No user found
</body>
</html>
```

And the code in scripts.js is

```
alert("hello");
```

Help me in this....
Not able to detect script tag.
This is working fine when use the same in html page, problem is only with the jsp page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/scripts.js"/>
```

use the`${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked much with `JSP` before, but looks like a path issue. Have you tried `/js/scripts.js` or `./js/scripts.js` or if you have some kind of static assets path defined somewhere, `<ASSETS_PATH>/js/scripts.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the path from the jsp to the js in a subdirectory of the parent directory? If so try changing the script tag to:

```
<script src="../js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question, which is a bit too complex for a code-only answer. You could improve it by adding additional explanation.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".